# loopback - Can POST be used to retrieve a resource

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Trying to use loopback framework for simulating a backend service. I need to retrieve an object using `POST` method. I know REST services typically allow `POST` to update/create a resource, but here, I cannot use `GET` with resource details for retrieving data.

In my case, `POST` data contains a few query fields that have to be used to query an object and send json back. Is this possible with loopback? I cannot use `GET` with query parms due to security restrictions with sending data as query parms in a `GET` URL.

here is post request data

```
[ { customer:"sam", city:"noWhere", } ]
```

the `POST` event should query by customer and city, then return matching customer object

```
[ { customer:"sam", postcode:"352345", city:"noWhere", country:"US" } ]
```

Comment: You can override built-in methods. Just read the documentation at http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Customizing+models, in the section 'Change the implementation of built-in methods '.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is an express http method override middleware: https://github.com/expressjs/method-override

And defining middleware in loopback: 
http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Defining+middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can override default loopback endpoint, like this

```
// Define custom remote method
Customer.fetch = function(oRequest, fnResponseCb) {
  /* Do staff to find customer and finally call fnResponseCb(null, oCustomer) */
}

// Override custom remote method
Customer.remoteMethod('fetch', {
  accepts: {
    arg: 'oRequest',
    type: 'object',
    http: { source: 'body' }
  },
  returns: {
    type: 'object',
    root: true
  },
  http: {
    path: '/',
    verb: 'POST'
  },
  description : 'Fetch Customer'
});
```